# Heroku SSH into worker node

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to SSH into a rails console using a worker process? I'm having trouble debugging a job running on a worker and would like to use `heroku run rails c` to begin debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, via `heroku ps:Exec` - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec